# Can I swap email provider to get around being blocked

Tags: email, gmail, domain, hotmail

I hosted my email with a company. One of my accounts was 'hacked' and some one sent a lot of spam. Now when I send an email to Hotmail I'm informed that

> Remote server replied: 550 SC-001. Unfortunately, messages from IPADDRESS weren't sent. Please contact your internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list.

This messages makes me think that the IP is blocked, not my domain name.

If I were to get GMAIL to host my business email, will the same issue persist? Or is it impossible to tell what the rules are for why my domain/hosting company IP is blocked (maybe the message is miss-leading)

Answer (score 1):

> This messages makes me think that the IP is blocked, not my domain name.

That's correct. Domains don't get blocked, IP addresses of the server(s) handling mail for a domain get blocked.

Moving to another email provider will solve your current problem of not being able to send email to Hotmail accounts. You also have the option of asking your current mail provider to get their servers unblocked. Before doing so they'll need you to demonstrate you've properly fixed the breach that led to the spam being sent through your account.

None of us like spam or the negative effects of having our mail blocked because of an account breach. I trust this experience will strengthen your resolve to protect your accounts with strong passwords and other available security measures, such as two-factor authentication.

Comment: Our passwords matched the rules set up by provider :(

Comment: I'm certain that would represent the *minimum* acceptable password strength. In today's security environment, a strong password is 1) 11+ characters in length, 2) Contains no dictionary words in any language, and 3) Is not used for *any* other account. All that said, it's entirely possible the compromise didn't take place by the attacker determining your password, as there are other attack methods. I can't guess as to what those would be not knowing the specifics of your environment.